# Реализация контекстного меню без родительского контрола в Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

Хочу контрол, который работает как попап меню, но не привязан к другому контролу. В окружении в которое пишу, знаю только хендл окна. При этом имеется желание писать на С# используя наверное Windows.Forms и писать поменьше без потери функциональности. Как это может выглядеть, нужно ли делать какую то форму или можно как то обойтись?

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал `ContextMenuStrip`. Невидимая форма у меня при этом тоже была, но для других целей - для регистрации хоткеев (да, сейчас знаю, что можно теоретически и без формы это сделать). Насколько я вижу, к форме я это меню не привязывал. Из минусов, что кнопка тогда почему-то на панели задач появлялась, когда меню делалось видимым. Но есть возможность, что я там что-то просто не так сделал.

PS: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=44022 - вполне возможно, что эта программа имеет ту же природу, что та, которую ты делаешь.